# how to persist a String/Object array such that indices and values are stored into separate columns in eclipselink

Tags: eclipselink, derby

Am using EclipseLink 2.4.2 with derby database. I have an Entity class which has a String array. Now, i need to map this array to a separate table 'MY_ARGS' such that index must be mapped to one column 'ARRAY_INDEX' and the value (at index) must be mapped to another column 'ARG'.

In hibernate we have 'array' element through which we can do this. Like below :

```
<array name="args" table="MY_ARGS" cascade="all">
    <key column="PARENT_ID"/>   
    <list-index column="ARRAY_INDEX" />
    <element type="string" column="ARG" length="16384" />
</array>
```

But in eclipse-link am not able to find any such element (am using eclipselink-orm.xml) through which i can achieve this!

Does Eclipselink support such array to table(multi-column) mapping?

I read about @Converter through which we can convert the data type while storing to/retrieving from DB. But it looks like converter deals with single column and cannot store to two columns simultaneously.

Is there a way that i can do this through converter or any such work around? (I prefer not to use collections)

Any quick help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

-Alekhya

Comment: If you are using JPA you would use an ElementCollection with an order field.  In native EclipseLink, the equivalent is called and aggregate mapping.

Comment: But i see that ElementCollection can be used only with Set,List,Map and Collections. I can't use it with plain array.